# How to disable default captcha input on Expression Engine

Tags: captcha

I tried to implement the below extension on Expression Engine. It is loading fine on the registration page. But I can see a text box along with this recaptcha box. Can any one explain me how to remove the existing text box?

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/recaptcha

Markup for the form is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jj8yk/
Screenshot of the problem is here: https://unsee.cc/pozisute/

Comment: Can you post a screen cap and the HTML that is being output for the entire form? The extension you link to overtakes the native CAPTCHA methods. In fact it won't work at all if you disable CAPTCHAs in your system preferences.

Comment: Please find here the HTML code http://jsfiddle.net/Jj8yk/
Here is the screenshot of the output https://unsee.cc/pozisute/

Comment: You should really consider using the addon Snaptcha ( https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/snaptcha ). Without using a captcha comment-spam is totally gone (honey-pot-principle). But well it will cost you 29 bucks.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra form input for the CAPTCHA that you do not need.

`<input type="text" name="captcha" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" style="width:140px;" />`

The ReCAPTCHA extension will dynamically create the form input for you in the `recaptcha_container` div, so you can remove that input from your form.

Comment: I understand that we should remove this input element. But where can I locate this form code in the ExpressionEngine application? I am new to EE and I really appreciate your patience and guidance. Also I wish to add this as a remark on the add on page itself - as this is the only addon available for reCAPTCHA.

Comment: It can be found in your [Member Profile Templates](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/member/#member-profile-templates). If you're using the Discussion Forums, then it will have its own profile templates.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Try going into the admin control panel->Members->Member Preferences, then choose "Enable Membership CAPTCHA" -> "No"</strike>

**EDIT:**
Apparently the recaptcha plugin does not function if disabling the native EE captcha function.  I'm using the strike-through here in case anyone can benefit from this knowledge in the future.